# Flutter Build Failed with an Exception of Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, maven, gradle

While building Flutter project, it suddenly stopped working and facing this issue.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
> ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Could not find org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/adw/library/discrete-seekbar/1.0.1/discrete-seekbar-1.0.1.pom
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/adw/library/discrete-seekbar/1.0.1/discrete-seekbar-1.0.1.pom
> > - https://jitpack.io/org/adw/library/discrete-seekbar/1.0.1/discrete-seekbar-1.0.1.pom
> > - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/org/adw/library/discrete-seekbar/1.0.1/discrete-seekbar-1.0.1.pom
> > Required by:
> > project :app
> > Could not resolve moe.feng.support.biometricprompt:library:1.0.2.
> > Required by:
> > project :app
> > > Could not resolve moe.feng.support.biometricprompt:library:1.0.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/moe/feng/support/biometricprompt/library/1.0.2/library-1.0.2.pom'.
> > > Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/moe/feng/support/biometricprompt/library/1.0.2/library-1.0.2.pom'.
> > Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
> > Could not find me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.4.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/me/relex/circleindicator/2.1.4/circleindicator-2.1.4.pom
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/me/relex/circleindicator/2.1.4/circleindicator-2.1.4.pom
> > - https://jitpack.io/me/relex/circleindicator/2.1.4/circleindicator-2.1.4.pom
> > - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/me/relex/circleindicator/2.1.4/circleindicator-2.1.4.pom
> > Required by:
> > project :app
> > Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2.
> > Required by:
> > project :app
> > > Could not resolve com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/2.8.2/android-pdf-viewer-2.8.2.pom'.
> > > Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/barteksc/android-pdf-viewer/2.8.2/android-pdf-viewer-2.8.2.pom'.
> > Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
> > Could not find com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/amulyakhare/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable/1.0.1/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable-1.0.1.pom
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/amulyakhare/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable/1.0.1/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable-1.0.1.pom
> > - https://jitpack.io/com/amulyakhare/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable/1.0.1/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable-1.0.1.pom
> > - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/amulyakhare/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable/1.0.1/com.amulyakhare.textdrawable-1.0.1.pom
> > Required by:
> > project :app > project :app_utils
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
> --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 52s

Project **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    ext.firebase_version = '28.4.2'
    ext.support_version = '1.0.0'
    ext.appcompat_version = '1.4.0'
    ext.recyclerview_version = '1.2.1'
    ext.vectordrawable_version = '1.1.0'
    ext.preference_version = '1.1.1'
    ext.material_version = '1.4.0'
    ext.play_services_version = '20.1.3'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app_utils')
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is Project **build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        ext.firebase_version = '28.4.2'
        ext.support_version = '1.0.0'
        ext.appcompat_version = '1.4.0'
        ext.recyclerview_version = '1.2.1'
        ext.vectordrawable_version = '1.1.0'
        ext.preference_version = '1.1.1'
        ext.material_version = '1.4.0'
        ext.play_services_version = '20.1.3'
    
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app_utils')
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

App **build.gradle**

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'skmchmobileapps'
            keyPassword 'Th3B3st$3cr3tK3y'
            storeFile file('../keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'Th3B3st$3cr3tK3y'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.skm.medicareskm"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app_utils')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_version")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display'

    //implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$support_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:$support_version"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$preference_version"
    implementation "androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:$vectordrawable_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$play_services_version"

    implementation 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'moe.feng.support.biometricprompt:library:1.0.2'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
}
```

Comment: it should be a proxy problem

Comment: No, it isn't a proxy problem. I haven't set any proxy. Moreover I am not behind any corporate proxy.